# Configure DNS Server greyed out Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

Noob question, sorry, but I have Googled, and asked and no one knows.

Basically the option to configure the DNS server is greyed out, along with just about every other option.  The only option available is Launch NSLookup. I tried to submit images but apparently I don't have the reputation points needed. :)

I have removed and added the DNS role a couple of times.  The option to setup the DNS is greyed out.  In fact, just about every option is greyed out.

What should I do? Just trying to set up some simple Alias and MX records. Thanks!

Comment: So you've added DNS as a server role but in server manager it's still greyed out? Have you tried opening the DNS MMC snap-in (dnsmgmt.msc)?

Comment: Also take a look at the event logs, there's one dedicated to DNS. This will hopefully point to the problem.

Comment: Do you have local Admin rights on the server?

Comment: @Chris Thorpe - looked through the event logs, found out the exact time it stopped working.  Looks to be a problem with Active Directory. Couldn't load Active Directory, and then started throwing all sorts of errors.

Comment: @Cheekaleak - Yes I have local Admin, seems to be related to Active Directory, so I am going to attack that angel.

Comment: @Lemb - haven't tried that yet.  Will try that and also try fixing Active Directory today.  Thanks all for your help. We will fix this yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory and DNS are tightly integrated. If you are running AD on this same server, and you've removed the DNS role from the server, you've probably stuffed AD quite badly.

If you have another AD-integrated DNS server in your environment, try setting your server's DNS entries to point to that remote server for its DNS lookups. Once you've done that, AD should be able to come up properly.

Once AD is up properly, you should be able to DCPROMO the server so that it's not a domain controller anymore, and once you've done that, you should be able to install a standalone DNS role without AD integration.

Answer (score 0):

Is the DNS service started? If not, it needs to be.

Comment: Yes it is started and set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

My case is very like yours. In my case, I tried this command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and then restarted DNS service, and after these I found all back to normal.